# calculate pass and fail count in sql/oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have database table in oracle like,

```
ID      status  cycle

T051    Passed   s1

T051    Failed   s1

T061    Failed   s1

T061    Failed   s1

T051    Failed   s2
```

i want output like this

```
ID   cycle pass   fail

T051   s1   1      0

T061   s1   0      1

T051   s2   0      1
```

Logic :-> if respective id&cycle any status is passed then its pass count 1 and if respective id&cycle all status is failed then fail count 1

can Anyone help here ?

Comment: I've removed some tags: `database` (you are not asking about how to design a database), `rdbms` (you are not asking about how an RDBMS works), and `mysql` (you say you are using Oracle which you also tagged and which is another DBMS than MySQL).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `MIN` and `MAX` aggregation functions to perform the equivalent of boolean logic for this query, using `MAX` to test if *any* status value is `Passed`, and `MIN` to check if any status value is *not* `Failed`:

```
SELECT ID, cycle,
       MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'Passed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pass,
       MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'Failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fail
FROM data
GROUP BY ID, cycle
ORDER BY ID, cycle
```

Output:

```
ID      CYCLE   PASS    FAIL
T051    s1      1       0
T051    s2      0       1
T061    s1      0       1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c63209aff0116be3d2af65ed7bb97ec)

Comment: thanks a lot man , this can be reduced numbers of lines in my sql query code once again thank you so much